# Can not get the file name using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help.I am unable to upload files into directory.I am explaining my code below.

```
 <?php
    $dbobj = new DBConnection();
    $imageName='newsimage';
    $imagePath="../uploads/news/";
    $dbobj->uploadImage($_FILES,$imageName,$imagePath,function($image){
                print_r($image);exit;
    });

    class DBConnection{
      public function uploadImage($files,$imageFieldName,$imageDirPath,$callback){
       // echo $imageField;exit;
       // print_r($files[$imageFieldName]);exit;
        $result=array();
        $imageName=generateRandomNumber().'_'.$_FILES[$imageFieldName]['name'];
        $target_dir = $imageDirPath;
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($imageName);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        //echo $files[$imageFieldName]["tmp_name"] ;exit;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //echo $imageName;exit;
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            $result['msg']="Sorry, file already exists.";
            $result['num']=0;
            $callback($result);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($_FILES[$imageFieldName]["size"] > 500000) {
            $result['msg']="Sorry, file size is large.";
            $result['num']=0;
            $callback($result);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if($imageFileType != "jpg") {
            $result['msg']="Sorry, only .jpg,.jpeg and .png files are allowed.";
            $result['num']=0;
            $callback($result);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            $result['msg']="Sorry, Your file could not uploaded.";
            $result['num']=0;
            $callback($result);
        }else{
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imageFieldName]['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                $result['msg']="Image has uploaded successfully.";
                $result['num']=1;
                $callback($result);
            }else{
                $result['msg']="Sorry, Your Image could not uploaded to the directory.";
                $result['num']=0;
                $callback($result);
            }
        }
   }
    }
    function generateRandomNumber(){
        $result=base_convert((float)rand()/(float)getrandmax() * round(microtime(true) * 1000), 10, 36);
        return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

Here i am trying to set `$_FILES` as parameter.inside `uploadImage` function i am trying to echo the image name but i am not getting it.So that i cannot upload the file into folder.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what does echo prints? blank?

Comment: I am always getting `Sorry, only .jpg,.jpeg and .png files are allowed` inside the callback function.

Comment: if you put an "echo $imageFileType" just before the if statement, what do you get?

Comment: i am getting the extension.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST, $_GET AND $_FILES are super global variable and they are always available. So passing them as function parameter is bad idea.

Instead passing $_FILES as function parameter try to get it in function itself.

```
class DBConnection{
  public function uploadImage($imageFieldName,$imageDirPath,$callback)
  {
     echo $_FILES[$imageFieldName]['name'];
     echo $_FILES[$imageFieldName]['tmp_name'];
  }

}
```

Hope so it will help you.

Comment: yes,But now i am getting the error message `Sorry, Your Image could not uploaded to the directory`.inside print_r .Please help me.

Comment: Does directory exist? if yes, does it has write permissions ?

Comment: didnt upload in provided directory... or maybe permission issue. @subhra

Comment: @subhra: your this condition is failed if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$imag.........} means not uploaded.

Comment: Do check if your directory is exist using function "is_dir(path)" and then assign write permission to it using "chmod(file,mode) " function. Once it done do check if it return true result. If result it true then try to upload file else resolve error return by these functions.